# Make javascript animate div and insert text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this box:

`<div class="message_box_red" id="commentForm_error_name" style="width: 409px; height: 0px; border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></div>`

And I would like to make it animate into this style: `"border: 2px solid; margin: 1px; padding: 7px; width: 409px;"`

And then as well insert some text into it, like `this is a test message` or something.

Comment: can you tell me here what you want

Comment: You can easily do this with CSS3 transition animations look at my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this [demo](http://jsbin.com/ewuyup/2)

**jQuery :**

```
$(".message_box_red").animate({

    "border":"2px solid",
    "margin":"1px",
    "padding":"7px",
    "width":" 409px",
    "height":"40px"

  },2000,function(){$(this).text("this is a test message")});
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ewuyup/11)

Comment: Thanks a ton! Can i somehow make the text fade in instead of comming instantly.?

Comment: yes. you can but you need to add a `span` in the div and make it `display:none` . for detail see the updated demo in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it uses CSS3 transitions triggered by changing of CSS class via java sscript:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>

    .message_box_red {

        width: 409px; 
        height: 50px; 
        border: 0; 
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: red;

        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
        transition: all 1s ease-out;


    }
    .message_box_red.animate {

        border: 2px solid; 
        margin: 1px; 
        padding: 7px; 
        width: 409px;
        height: 100px;
        background: blue;
        color: #fff;

    }

</style>

<script>

    function change_class(did, content) {

        var div_change = document.getElementById(did);
        div_change.setAttribute("class", "message_box_red animate");
        div_change.innerHTML = content;

    }

</script>

</head>
<body>
    Click on DIV!
    <div class="message_box_red" id="commentForm_error_name" onclick="change_class('commentForm_error_name','this is the future content of DIV...');">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Live example:**
http://simplestudio.rs/yard/div_animate/chng_color.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this doesn't change the text. But then I could use the code from the above answer.